# How can I make this code delayed for 15 seconds then running?

Tags: javascript, delay

I want this JavaScript code delay for 15 seconds then run the code but it doesn't work.

I was tried setTimeout or something like that but it not delay for 15s.
Here the code: `<https://codepen.io/Anonymous111111/pen/LYqXKVY>`

Any ideas to make this code delayed for me pleaseee

Comment: Please put the code in the question. The easier you make it for others to see and understand your code, the quicker and more accurate the answers you'll get

Comment: I assure you, setTimeout works in browsers. It's entirely possible to do something after 15 seconds.

Comment: Please share the snippet of your code where you implemented `setTimeout`? This will help in understanding how you've applied it. Remember, the time is in milliseconds, so 15 seconds should be `15000`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delay using `setTimeout`. See the code below for an example.

```js
function startTyping() {
  // Code for the type animation
}
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(startTyping, 5000);
}
```

You can learn more about `setTimeout` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Comment: The asker has said they've already used `setTimeout`

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's highly unlikely `setTimeout` is broken in any modern browser.

Comment: @evolutionxbox He is using `setTimeout` in the `tick` method, not _before_ starting with the typing